# Suming MySQL existing number with varriable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating script which would sum number which is in database and the varriable - `$currentPercent`. But i can't find any topic where it explains how to do that. Here is my script part which only updates the existing value... So i ask again, how could i sum existing value and the `$currentTasken` varriable?

```
$inss = mysql_query("UPDATE dotp_tasks SET task_percent_complete = '$currentPercent' WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'") ;
```

UPDATED: For example `$currentPercent` is number 8. And the number in database is 82. And then sum it 90.

Comment: less information. please elaborate.

Comment: I want to sum existing number `WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'` and the  `$currentPercent`.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected end results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem:

```
$inss = mysql_query("UPDATE dotp_tasks 
SET task_percent_complete = task_percent_complete + '$currentPercent'
WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'") ;
```

But personally, I would suggest you to search more before asking these kind of questions

Comment: Value just stays the same. 0. Even if i adding 95

Comment: if the previous value null ?

Comment: @gerogecj Not Null, 0.

Comment: Try this :  $inss = mysql_query("UPDATE dotp_tasks 
SET task_percent_complete = ifnull(task_percent_complete, 0) + ifnull('$currentPercent', 0) 
WHERE task_id='$currentTasken'")

Comment: Here is the error http://s24.postimg.org/bw3j58gkl/Untitleddd.png And here is jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jaLaoybu/

Comment: I cannot understand your code . but this query will run : Update table_name set int_field = int_field + 10 where id =1; Make  sure your php variables are having proper values

Answer (score 0):

Here you go try this:

```
 $inss = mysql_query("UPDATE dotp_tasks 
    SET 
 task_percent_complete=(select sum(A.task_percent_complete + '$currentPercent') 
    from dotp_tasks A where A.task_id='$currentTasken')
    where task_id='$currentTasken'");
```

Comment: execute this part in mysql to check if u get a output from this select sum(A.task_percent_complete + '$currentPercent') 
    from dotp_tasks A where A.task_id='$currentTasken'